# How to show properly accents in git diff output

Tags: git

When I run git diff command, in the files list all files with accents are poorly displayed :

```
 git diff --name-status xxxx yyyyyy
```

return

```
M       "\303\251\303\251.txt"
```

How I can preserve accents to have this ? :

```
M       "éé.txt"
```

Thanks

Edit : I specify that the file is encoded in UTF-8 and I tried with git 2.3.2 from OSX and git 1.9.1 from Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
git config core.quotepath off   
# or
git config --global core.quotepath off
```

See [Git for Windows Unicode Support -- Settings](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-for-Windows-Unicode-Support#settings).

> By default, git will print non-ASCII file names in quoted octal notation, i.e. "`\nnn\nnn...`".
>   This can be disabled with:

```
 git config [--global] core.quotepath off
```

I just tested it with the [latest Git for Windows 2.3.5](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).