# git show name only with filename containing special char interpret the character

Tags: git, non-ascii-characters, git-show

I have a commit number , and I want to get all the file from the commit number and then display them in a text file, where latter on, I will loop in the file and checkout each of them.

I have manage to do it with the following command :

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only  commit_no >> cpath.txt
```

The problem is that If a filename contains special char like in the picture:
[image]

The filename is interpreted wrongly in the text file , thus when checking it out will failed. Here is how it is showing :

"force-app/main/default/layouts/Campaign-DM Campagne Locale M\303\250re.layout-meta.xml"
force-app/main/default/layouts/Campaign-DM Sous-Campagne Locale.layout-meta.xml
"force-app/main/default/layouts/Campaign-Validation Campagne m\303\250re.layout-meta.xml"

Is there a parameter I need to use whe using the git show command to inteprete the filename with special as it is originally ?

If not then how to replace the special char in there automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across a post where the solution is working for me : [How to show properly accents in git diff output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667339/how-to-show-properly-accents-in-git-diff-output)

I had to setup my git config using following command :

```
git config core.quotepath off
```

Thus, git will not replace the special char